# Change text of a <label> dynamicly based on <select>

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have the following code on a JSP file, where I want the text for the `<label>` named 'complemento' to be changed according to the option selected in the `<select>` named 'tipo'. is there any error with the javascript code, because when I open the page in the browser, it doesn't work as desired.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
      <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>Cadastra Usuario</title>

         <script>
            function mudaTexto(tipo) {
               var opcao_index = tipo.selectedIndex;
               var opcao = tipo.options[opcao_index].value;
               if(opcao == '0')
                  document.getElementById('complemento').innerHTML = 'Periodo';
               else if(opcao == '1')
                  document.getElementById('complemento').innerHTML = 'Titulo';
               else
                  document.getElementById('complemento').innerHTML = 'Status';
            }
         </script>

      </head>
      <body>

         <p align="center">
            <span class="usuario">${nome}</span> | <strong> Hora Livre</strong> | <a href="/hora_livre/ProcessaSaida"> Sair</a>
         </p>

         <p align="center">
            <form method="post" action="/hora_livre/CadastraUsuario">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>Login: </td> <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Digite uma Senha: </td> <td><input type="password" name="password">      
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Repita a Senha: </td> <td><input type="password" name="senha"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Tipo de usuario: </td>
                  <td>
                     <select name="tipo" onchange="mudatexto(this.form.tipo)">
                        <option value="0">Aluno</option>
                        <option value="1">Professor</option>
                        <option value="2">Funcionario</option>
                     </select>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Nome Completo: </td> <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td><label for="complemento">Periodo</label></script></label> </td> 
                  <td>    <input type="text" name="complemento"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr colspan=2>
                  <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
      </p>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no element with the id=complemento . Fix it by adding the id to your input

```
<td><label for="complemento">Periodo</label></script></label> </td> <td><input id="complemento"  type="text" name="complemento"></td>
```

also use value instead of innerHtml because it's an input

```
if(opcao == '0')
    document.getElementById('complemento').value= 'Periodo';
else if(opcao == '1')
    document.getElementById('complemento').value= 'Titulo';
else
    document.getElementById('complemento').value= 'Status';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mudaTexto, not mudatexto. You have to spell the function name correctly.
JavaScript is case sensitive.

Your POST request returns:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "error": false
}
```

You also don't have an element with such an id, just the name.

And don't use .innerHTML. It's .value.

Tested it and worked.

Answer (score 1):

ok as Andrei said;

the label, the text of which you want to change, has the NAME `complemento`, but you are looking for an element with the ID `complemento` and therefore it will not work.

And then, the function names are case sensitive like the other guys said, `mudatexto` should be `mudaTexto` and you're trying to access tipo, as if it has an id attribute defined, but it's only got a name; `this.form.tipo` will not work, rather use `this.value`, then your html for tipo will look like this;

```
<select name="tipo" onchange="mudaTexto(this.value)">
   <option value="0">Aluno</option>
   <option value="1">Professor</option>
   <option value="2">Funcionario</option>
</select>
```

you can either try Andrei's solution or you can use `document.getElementsByName()[0]` instead of `document.getElementById()`, which will look like this;

```
function mudaTexto(tipo) {
   var opcao_index = tipo.selectedIndex;
   var opcao = tipo.options[opcao_index].value;
   if(opcao == '0'){
      document.getElementsByName('complemento')[0].innerHTML = 'Periodo';
   }else if(opcao == '1'){
      document.getElementsByName('complemento')[0].innerHTML = 'Titulo';
   }else{
      document.getElementsByName('complemento')[0].innerHTML = 'Status';
   }
}
```

also; you should take a look at using angularjs, it will remove any need to do such a thing with javascript or jquery.